# Fluent NHibernate PersistenceSpecification not-null property references a null or transient value error

Tags: unit-testing, fluent-nhibernate, persistence

I've been struggling with this mess for days now, trying to figure out the exact reason for the error. One word, FAILURE! Basically I have been trying to unit test a `ClassMap` that I've written with some `reference` that references another `reference`.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void IssueReturnRegisterMap_Create_Success()
    {
        var maxDifference = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(990);
        BookSize sz = new BookSize() { ID = "1", Name = "A" };
        Department dpt = new Department() { ID = "1", Name = "Philosophy" };
        Author auth = new Author() { ID = "2", FirstName = "Wise", LastName = "Person" };
        Publisher pub = new Publisher() { ID = "1", Name = "Pub1", Address = "Address 1" };
        Language lang = new Language() { ID = "1", Name = "Lang1" };
        Patron ptrn = new Patron()
        {
            ID = "1",
            FirstName = "First",
            LastName = "Last",
            Age = 82,
            Address = "Address1",
            Gender = "Male",
            Occupation = "Occupation1",
            Telephone1 = "01234567890",
            Telephone2 = "01234567890"
        };

        Book book = new Book()
        {
            ID = "1",
            Name = "Book1",
            Number = "12",
            BookSize = sz,
            Department = dpt,
            Author = auth,
            Commentator = "Another wiseman",
            Publisher = pub,
            Language = lang,
        };
        Member member = new Member()
        {
            ID = "1",
            Patron = ptrn,
            IsRegistered = true
        };

        //Edit: Acc. to Firo's suggestion
        Database.Session.Save( sz );
        Database.Session.Save( dpt );
        Database.Session.Save( auth );
        Database.Session.Save( lang );
        Database.Session.Save( pub );
        Database.Session.Save( ptrn );
        Database.Session.Save( book ); //@Firo: Throws same exception here! :-(
        Database.Session.Save( member );

        new PersistenceSpecification<IssueReturnEntry>( Database.Session, new CustomEqualityComparer() )
        .CheckProperty( x => x.ID, "1" )
        .CheckReference( x=> x.Book, book )
        .CheckReference( x => x.Member, member )
        .CheckProperty( x => x.IssuedBy, "Librarian" )
        .CheckProperty( x => x.IssueDate, DateTime.Now, new DateTimeEqualityComparer( maxDifference ) )
        .CheckProperty( x => x.DueDate, DateTime.Now, new DateTimeEqualityComparer( maxDifference ) )
        .CheckProperty( x => x.ReturnDate, DateTime.Now, new DateTimeEqualityComparer( maxDifference ) )
        .CheckProperty( x => x.ReturnBy, "User" )
        .VerifyTheMappings();
    }
```

As you can clearly see that my `Book` is made of `references` like `BookSize`, `Department` etc. And then that `Book` itself becomes a `references` for `IssueReturnRegister` map. Same goes for the `Member`. It throws a 'not-null property references a null or transient value error' exception for `BookSize` object. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any Fluent nHibernate experts out there?

Comment: can you show your euqals and gethashcode implementation in effect for booksize?

Comment: `if (x is BookSize && y is BookSize)
            {
                return (((BookSize)x).ID == ((BookSize)y).ID) && (((BookSize)x).Name == ((BookSize)y).Name)
                    && (((BookSize)x).Length == ((BookSize)y).Length) && (((BookSize)x).Width == ((BookSize)y).Width);
            }`

This is the equals method I've got for EqualityComparer. I don't have any GetHashCode method yet.

Comment: Is every expert on Fluent Nhibernate on a holiday?!

Comment: gethashcode is actually very important so try to use mine to test the issue

Comment: OK I will try that. However, the unit test works for `Book` object, which has `BookSize`, `Department` etc references, without having to implement `GetHasCode`!

Comment: your comment contradicts with the first comment on my answer. Does it throw when saving the book? Have you saved booksize before or not? sCan you show the Idmapping of book and booksize

Comment: I've posted the code for `BookMap` `BookSizeMap` and then the unit test for `Book` entity which passes without having to save the `BookSize` or any need of `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`. Could you please shed some light on why one test would pass and other would fail, as I've lost all my hair scratching my head?

Answer (score 0):

the error means that Booksize is referenced by an entity to be stored but is itself not stored and can not be stored in this action because cascading is disabled.

so either do

- `References(x => x.BookSize).Cascade.All()` in the mapping or
- `Database.Session.Save(bz)` before running `PersistenceSpecification`

same for all other referenced entities

Update: persistent entities should have an Equals method taking the id into account

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as BookSize;
    return other != null && (Id == 0) ? ReferenceEquals(this, other) : Id == other.Id;
}

private int? _hashcode;
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return _hashcode.HasValue ? _hashcode.Value : _hashcode = Id;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks very much for replying. I knew that the reference `BookSize` is not being saved, I was looking for HOW to do it, which you provided me with. Thanks for that. I tried what you suggested and it still throws the same exception but rather when I try to do `Database.Session.Save(book)` as I edited in my question. :-(

Comment: where does variable book come from? it is not defined in the code posted

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Firo, I don't think my reply was readable enough hence posting it here again.

```
if (x is BookSize && y is BookSize)
{ 
return (((BookSize)x).ID == ((BookSize)y).ID) && (((BookSize)x).Name == ((BookSize)y).Name) && (((BookSize)x).Length == ((BookSize)y).Length) && (((BookSize)x).Width == ((BookSize)y).Width);
}
```

This is the equals method I've got for EqualityComparer. I don't have any GetHashCode method yet.

Answer (score 0):

My `BookMap` and `BookSizeMap` are as followed and then follows the unit test for `Book` entity using `PersistenceSpecification` which passes without any such exception (mind you, I already tried doing as per `Book` entity's unit test and didn't work for `IssueRegisterEntry` entity.

```
public class BookMap : ClassMap<Book>
{
    public BookMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.BookSize)
        .Column("SizeID");
        References(x => x.Department)
        .Column("DepartmentID");
        Map(x => x.Number);
        Map(x => x.Edition);
        Map(x => x.CopyNumber);
        References(x => x.Author)
        .Column("AuthorID");
        Map(x => x.Commentator);
        References(x => x.Publisher)
        .Column("PublisherID");
        References(x => x.Language)
        .Column("LanguageID");
        Map(x => x.Cupboard);
        Map(x => x.IsIssued);
        Map(x => x.IsDeleted);
        Table("Books");
    }
}

public class BookSizeMap : ClassMap<BookSize>
{
    public BookSizeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Length);
        Map(x => x.Width);
    }
}

    [TestMethod]
    public void BookMapping_Create_Success()
    {
        new PersistenceSpecification<Book>( Database.Session, new CustomEqualityComparer() )
        .CheckProperty(x => x.ID, "1")
        .CheckProperty(x => x.Name, "My Experiments with Truth")
        .CheckReference(x => x.BookSize, new BookSize() { ID = "2", Name = "A" })
        .CheckReference(x => x.Department, new Department() { ID = "3", Name = "Autobiography" })
        .CheckProperty(x => x.Number, "ABG.a.1")
        .CheckProperty(x => x.Edition, "12")
        .CheckProperty(x => x.CopyNumber, "13")
        .CheckReference(x => x.Author, new Author() { ID = "4", FirstName = "Mohandas", LastName = "Gandhi" })
        .CheckProperty(x => x.Commentator, "Comm1")
        .CheckReference(x => x.Publisher, new Publisher() { ID = "5", Name = "ABC", Address = "XYZ" })
        .CheckReference(x => x.Language, new Language() { ID = "6", Name = "Lang1" })
        .CheckProperty(x => x.IsIssued, true)
        .CheckProperty(x => x.IsDeleted, false)
        .VerifyTheMappings();
    }
```

Comment: why is Id a string? you do not specify any generator for the id which defaults to native/identity so Id should be readonly and `.CheckProperty(x => x.ID, "1")` is nonsense then. the id is assigned through the db.

Comment: `ID` will be more like a GUID number (not GUID though) and will be generated by a different class, but that's not the problem! If not so, then how can `.CheckProperty(x => x.ID, "1")` works for `Book` entity and not for entity in question?!

Comment: add `.GeneratedBy.Assigned()` to the Id mapping and see if it helps